# What is the noun form of explicit which implies exactly two states?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the noun form of explicit. The word explicitness seems to me to imply many "levels" of explicitness, but I want to know if is there a noun form of explicit whose value can be either "explicit" or "not explicit".

An example of how one might use this word:

> It may be difficult to interpret the ***_*__*_*__*_*___** (explicitness) of this song because it is in a foreign language.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the noun form might be used?

Comment: Done. Any help now?

Comment: "I know it when I see it." - [Potter Steward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potter_Stewart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Salacity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/salacity)**: the state of being salacious, where salacious means obscene; grossly indecent. (alternative to *salaciousness*)

Or simply **[vulgarity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vulgarity)**: the state or quality of being vulgar; where *vulgar* is indecent; obscene; lewd; crude; coarse; unrefined; current; popular; common.

The simplest may be **[crudity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crudity)**: the state or quality of being crude; where crude means undisguised or blunt;

Of less common use:

**[Lubricity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lubricity)**: lewdness; lustfulness: lasciviousness; salaciousness; something that arouses lasciviousness, especially pornography.

Answer (score 0):

"Duplicity" is infrequently used in the sense of "having two states" (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duplicity). Perhaps that is what you want?

It does not *necessarily* imply that said two states are "explicit" and "not explicit" though.

Comment: I am actually talking about explicit in the context of swearing.

Comment: As the level of graphic detail in said words can be offensive in variable amounts (what is explicit for a four-year old might not be so for an 18-year old), I'm not sure there is a binary descriptor for it. I'd like to learn if there is, though.

For what it's worth, 'explicitness' itself seems to be pretty usable in the form of a variable descriptor of graphic language as you mentioned (e.g. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/explicitness)